# My Bluetooth stopped working for seemingly no reason

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

My laptop (HP Stream 11, Ubuntu 20.04) has just today stopped seeing it's built in Bluetooth.

```
        No Bluetooth Found
Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.
```

It was around when I started using Bluetooth again that it stopped working. (I haven't used Bluetooth in a while) When I run `systemctl status bluetooth.service` I get this:

```
noah@noah-HP-Stream:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jul 23 19:54:52 noah-HP-Stream systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jul 23 19:55:25 noah-HP-Stream systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jul 23 19:56:14 noah-HP-Stream systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jul 23 20:02:36 noah-HP-Stream systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Running `systemctl start bluetooth` doesn't return anything, and adds to the list at the bottom of the first command. **Before you mark this as a duplicate**, I have tried the solutions from the other questions and none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the solution is always in the last place you check, because the way I fixed it was by powering my laptop off, shaking it, and powering it back on. Huh.

*(to be clear, I had already tried restarting)*